# Estimating Sample Size with no Standard Deviation

Tags: t-test, standard-deviation, two-sample

I am conducting a one-sided, independent two-sample t-test for a gender study and I can guesstimate my effect size from previous studies. I want 95% significance, 80% power. I am looking to calculate appropriate sample size and realise I need the standard deviation to do this.

**Is there any way of approximating the standard deviation from the effect size? My lecturer said doubling the effect size provides a rough approximation of an appropriate standard deviation. Is this correct? Why is this the case??**

Thanks in advance.

Note: effect size is around +16 percentage points (control group mean estimation: 34%, treatment group mean estimation: 50%).

Comment: <p>I don't have enough reputation points to comment...so I will do so here:</p>
<p>¿What are the &ldquo;units&rdquo; of your effect size?</p>
<p>I ask this clarification, because many effect sizes are measured in <em>standard deviation</em> units. In this case, you can treat everything as $z$-scores, and assume the standard deviation is one.</p>